# Adding a page link in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to add a page link in CakePHP using:

```
<?php echo $html->link('Home', '/notes/index');?>
```

It doesn't seem to output the proper link.

What I'd want is something like this:

```
<a href="/cake/cake_startab/notes/index/" alt="Home">Home </a>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You're going to need to explain a bit more. Are you using a content system or framework? What code is in the function `link`?

Comment: What is `$html`? Do you imply that the first example does not work but the second does? It is not totally clear...

Comment: ya u r right writing with 1st one is not working but using 2nd one its working fine.........

Comment: @rajesh: Are you getting any error message when you use the first one or what is the output?

Comment: Actually i m just checking the path at the bottom of the browser 
its not representing correct controller path
but with using anchor tag <a> its showing perfectly.....

Comment: @rajesh, what is the resultant <a> you get when using the html helper?

Comment: Are you expecting the link to be `<a href="/notes/index/" alt="Home">Home</a>`? Or what else is the problem? This is the expected output if your app is in `/cake/cake_startab/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use a url array

```
<?php echo $html->link('Home', array('controller'=>'notes','action'=>'index')); ?>
```

This will work for you. You will not be able to use an absolute path :)

Check out the manual page, http://api.cakephp.org/class/html-helper#method-HtmlHelperlink

Answer (score 0):

Create individual controller for this page or create routing for this page in PagesController.

Comment: Could you improve your answer, or just remove it? It doesn't make much sense right now.